# Insert Several Similar Rows with One Query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Consider a table with 2 fields:

```
 tbl(Id int primary key,Name varchar(100))
```

Assume that this table contains one row with `Id=3` and some **unknown** `Name`.

```
 Id   |   Name
 ---------------
 3    |   *****
```

I have an array of `Id`s, for example: `array(4,6,7,10)`
How to put these `Id`s with the `Name` of row with `Id=3` into this table with one query, So that the resulted table would be:

```
 Id   |   Name
 ---------------
 3    |   *****
 ----------------
 4    |   *****
 ----------------
 6    |   *****
 ----------------
 7    |   *****
 ----------------
 10   |   *****
```

I can not use the `Name`'s value in the query.

I am thinking of a query like this:

```
insert into tbl(Id,Name) select (4,6,7,10),Name from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 queries, 1st get the name and 2nd do the insert with multi row insert

```
INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```